# iOS MAKImageGalleryView downloading photos using AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I am trying to do photo gallery based on [MAKImageGalleryView](https://github.com/diniska/MAKImageGalleryView), but I need download images from server, so I use `AFImageDownloader` ([AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)).

By the documentation of `MAKImageGalleryView` I have to implement this method:

**MAKImageGalleryView.h**

```
- (void)loadImageInGallery:(MAKImageGalleryView *)galleryView atIndex:(NSInteger)index callback:(void(^)(UIImage *))callback;
```

**MAKImageGalleryView.m**

```
#import "MAKImageGalleryView.h"

- (void)loadImageForRow:(NSInteger)row withBlockToCell:(MAKImageGalleryViewImageCell *)cell {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSUInteger key = random();
        cell.blockLoadingId = key;
        [self.imageGalleryDataSource loadImageInGallery:self atIndex:row callback:^(UIImage *image) {
            if (cell.blockLoadingId == key) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (cell.blockLoadingId == key) { //if still not reused
                        cell.image = image;
                    }
                });
            }
        }];
    });
}
```

So I create something like that:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)loadImageInGallery:(MAKImageGalleryView *)galleryView atIndex:(NSInteger)index callback:(void(^)(UIImage *))callback{

    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/image%i.jpg", index];

    AFImageDownloader* download = [[AFImageDownloader alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
        timeoutInterval:60];
    [download downloadImageForURLRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, UIImage * image) {
        NSLog(@"Success download image");
        callback(image);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error download image");
    }];
```

Result:
Time to time I see some photos, and don't see others.

Comment: You can use `SDWebImage` for downloading as well as caching images. It's a great library to handle image downloading and caching.

Comment: @iPeter thank you, but I think the result will be the same.

Comment: @Peter just a shot in the dark: Have you checked that those responses are on main thread? It might be just an UI issue it they are not.

Comment: @MaticOblak How to check it?

Comment: @Peter the easiest if simply putting a breakpoint in it and check on the left panel which thread you are on. Alternatively you can check using code by printing `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: @MaticOblak: I was not promoting anything here, I was just suggesting something that helped me to handle something easily, that's it.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes, here is some trouble, in case everything is okay, I see photo, I see NSLog "Success download image", and [NSThread isMainThread] is equal to YES. In other case I don't see anything (NSLog "Success download image" or NSLog "Error download image"). So trouble with Thread. How to fix it?

Comment: @Peter not seeing any log at all does not indicate there is an issue with your thread. This sounds more like there is an issue with `AFImageDownloader` or that your connection breaks and the operation will wait for whatever the timeout duration is (might be very long) and you would then receive an error that your request timed out.  Check if you can reduce the timeout interval and confirm that. Another thing I can think of is you need to retain your `download` object which in your case simply add `NSLog(@"%@", download)` in any of the completions to confirm the fix.

Comment: @MaticOblak I'm tried to set timeout equal to 1, but I still have no error message. So I think it don't even run at all. I edit my post, and add some code from MAKImageGalleryView.m to show some manipulation with Thread in MAKImageGalleryView. So what next?

Comment: @Peter next as said is retaining downloader. In your case all you need is `NSLog(@"Success download image %@", download);` inside your block.

Comment: @MaticOblak It's magic! How does it work?

Comment: @MaticOblak: I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As debugged by using comments it seems that `AFImageDownloader` needs to be retained until the operation is complete. If not then there is a persistent chance the downloader will be released too soon and terminate its download automatically.

You need to retain your downloader. The most straight forward solution is to use a strong property and modify your call to:

```
- (void)loadImageInGallery:(MAKImageGalleryView *)galleryView atIndex:(NSInteger)index callback:(void(^)(UIImage *))callback{

    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/image%i.jpg", index];

    AFImageDownloader* download = [[AFImageDownloader alloc] init];
    self.currentDownloader = download;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
        timeoutInterval:60];
    ...
```

If you have multiple downloaders then you will need to add them into array but also remove them:

```
- (void)loadImageInGallery:(MAKImageGalleryView *)galleryView atIndex:(NSInteger)index callback:(void(^)(UIImage *))callback{

    NSString * imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/image%i.jpg", index];

    AFImageDownloader* download = [[AFImageDownloader alloc] init];
    [self.currentDownloaders addObject: download];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
        timeoutInterval:60];
    [download downloadImageForURLRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, UIImage * image) {
        NSLog(@"Success download image");
        [self.currentDownloaders removeObject: download];
        callback(image);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest * request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"Error download image");
        [self.currentDownloaders removeObject: download];
    }];
```

Or as we did it with test you could simply let the block retain the download:

By simply calling `NSLog(@"Success download image %@", download);` inside any of the blocks will force the block to retain `download`. And as long as the block is retained so will the download be. That is at least until one of the blocks has been called.

This is the cleanest procedure but since this object is not your creation you need to check if these objects do get deallocated at some point. If they are not done correctly then this code will produce a retain cycle and with it a memory leak.

So before you use this last procedure please check the following:

Subclass `AFImageDownloader`, override `dealloc` and print something like `NSLog(@"Did deallocate");` and use this subclass instead of your `AFImageDownloader`. If you see a log "Did deallocate" at some point then it is safe to use the "log trick". If not then you should not use this procedure as it will produce memory leaks!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything!